# consolidate .CSV lines (output from MySQL) based on one field and calculating sum for another field

Tags: text-processing, mysql

EDIT:

I will work on the solution proposed by toppk.

---

**How can I tweak my SELECT statement to do this?**

I want to combine matching lines from a monthly billing report, consolidating entries when they're for the same task.  A script pulls MySQL queries from my support tickets and dumps to a csv.  Typically I'll give it a time range of the prior month.

Many tasks get multiple time entries, and it would be preferable to consolidate them into a single line.

The script sorts by billable client and then by task, yielding a .CSV for the final report.  I've edited the example for privacy, but the billable totals are correct in the true reports.

```
Desired result from this sample output:
 - combine the three entries for ticket 8732 (audio system) into a single 630m (10.5h) line
 - combine ticket 8789 (cabinet meeting) into one 120m line
 - combine ticket 8182 (backups) into a single 240m line
et cetera
```

sample .CSV excerpt:
listed: client; ticket title; ticket number; time (m); time (h); our internal dept label

```
"client","subject","#","time","hours","status","dept"
,,,,,
"museum","audio system: reconfigure and test","8732","30","0.5","closed","Production"
"museum","audio system: reconfigure and test","8732","210","3.5","closed","Production"
"museum","audio system: reconfigure and test","8732","390","6.5","closed","Production"
"museum","documentary premiere in gallery","8733","240","4.0","closed","Production"
"museum","audio and Lectern support","8767","30","0.5","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","County manager cabinet meeting","8789","30","0.5","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","County manager cabinet meeting","8789","90","1.5","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","mass file duplication","8834","45","0.75","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","audio system support","8835","45","0.75","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","PC browser support","8836","45","0.75","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","audio system issues","8840","30","0.5","closed","IT_Support"
"museum","equipment move","8871","75","1.25","closed","IT_Support"
,,,1335,22.25,hours
,,,,,
,,,,,
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","ongoing: manual Eaglesoft backup","8182","30","0.5","open","IT_Support"
"dental office","failed monitor support","8724","30","0.5","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","backups server crash","8726","135","2.25","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","backups server crash","8726","75","1.25","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","hypervisor virtual backups","8730","120","2","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","panoramic x-ray access issue","8734","105","1.75","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","unusual phone behavior / call quality issues","8744","75","1.25","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","server room power issue","8752","75","1.25","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","Eaglesoft error","8759","30","0.5","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","server issue: filesystem management","8761","75","1.25","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","server room power issue","8780","45","0.75","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","Eaglesoft schedule problem","8782","60","1","closed","IT_Support"
"dental office","PC power problem","8865","105","1.75","closed","IT_Support"
,,,1290,21.50,hours
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,Total,13125 m,218.75,hours
```

(so the museum section would end up having nine lines of output instead of twelve)

Here's the SELECT statement--piped through awk and sed for the CSV.

```
/usr/bin/mysql osticket -Be "SELECT
  ost_organization.name as 'client', ost_ticket__cdata.subject, ost_ticket.ticket_id as '#', ost_thread_entry.time_spent as 'time', ost_thread_entry.time_type as 'how', ost_ticket_status.state as status, ost_department.name as dept
FROM ost_organization
JOIN ost_user
  ON ost_organization.id = ost_user.org_id
JOIN ost_ticket
  ON ost_user.id = ost_ticket.user_id
JOIN ost_ticket_status
  on ost_ticket_status.id = ost_ticket.status_id
JOIN ost_ticket__cdata
  ON ost_ticket.ticket_id = ost_ticket__cdata.ticket_id
JOIN ost_thread
  ON ost_thread.object_id = ost_ticket.ticket_id
JOIN ost_department
  ON ost_department.id = ost_ticket.dept_id
JOIN ost_thread_entry
  ON ost_thread_entry.thread_id = ost_thread.id 
 AND ost_thread_entry.time_type != 7
 AND ost_thread_entry.time_bill = 1
 AND ost_thread_entry.staff_id = $MyAgentID
 AND ost_thread_entry.time_spent != 0 and ost_thread_entry.created regexp '$Today'
ORDER BY $SortFlag
;" | awk -F"    " 'BEGIN{OFS=FS};{print $1,$2,$3,$4,($4/60),$6,$7}' | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/ /","/g'
```

So I'd need to calculate the sum of [ost_thread_entry.time_spent]... but only in cases where [ost_ticket.ticket_id] is the same.  **How can I tweak this SELECT statement to do that?**

Notes:

- The "$Today" variable is whatever date I give the script as a CLI argument (e.g. 2022-08 for last month). It defaults to [today], e.g. 2022-09-06.
- The ticket system is OS Ticket, with a 3rd-party mod for time tracking.
- The DB stores time in minutes--script calculates hours from that.
- My first inclination was to use awk similar to the below, but this would require the script first evaluating duplicate lines, which strikes me as far less efficient.  My gut says there's a smarter database solution.

`awk -F '","' '$3 == 8182 {print $4}' report.csv`

Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL solution or an `awk`-type solution? Me, I'd be looking at solving it at the SQL level

Comment: you can use `SUM(ost_thread_entry.time_spent)` with   `GROUP BY  ost_ticket.ticket_id`, see an explanation here https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php .  I agree, this is best done in SQL, and not shell.

Comment: Yeah, doing this database problem outside of the database is just wrong. It's literally what SQL was invented for.

Comment: @toppk: Thanks; I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @roaima: Sorry; describing my thought process seemed important (or maybe to preclude awk solutions if a DB solution exists).  Brevity's never been my strong suit.  Question edited slightly to emphasize MySQL...thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your sql question, but: 1. You can set awk's output field separator (OFS) to whatever you like (including to FS), so you don't have to manually do the field seps. e.g. `awk -F"    " 'BEGIN{OFS=FS};{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$8}'`.  2. Instead of using a combination of bash, awk, sed, and the mysql command-line client, you would be **much** better off using perl and [DBI](https://dbi.perl.org/) and DBI's mysql driver, [DBD::mysql](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql).  and perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). If you can write awk & sed, perl is easy.

Comment: Another alternative, instead of Text::CSV would be to use both DBD::mysql **and** [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV), a module for interacting with CSV files as if they were SQL databases. Then you could SELECT from the mysql db, and INSERT into a CSV "database". I'm not sure if that's terribly useful for mysql->csv, but I've done similar with mysql->postgres and postgres->mysql etc in the past. Finally, 3. If you really don't like perl, python also has libraries for working with mysql and csv...but if you're coming from awk + sed + bash + etc, perl will be more familiar & easier.

Comment: @cas: thanks for the ideas. I wrote this script in (2018?), so I had to reexamine the sed statement to reply. I'd like to think I tried simplifying the awk before inserting the extra sed iterations, but I honestly don't recall. The script (depending on CLI flags) will dump to console or .CSV, or just print a summary total hours--I probably just copied the entire section and slapped a sed on it. Always in a rush in this place, and I cringe at the bad habits I'll need to heal when I finally escape. :,(  The DBD::CSV is intriguing; I may explore it. I'll need to learn some Perl first though.

Comment: @cas: I've adopted your streamlined awk statement.  I'm also now using awk to calculate the hours from the minutes (question updated to reflect both).  Still wrestling SQL syntax to implement toppk's suggestion; when I get that working I'll post it as an answer.